# Adding minimum characters to this regex

Tags: c++, regex

I currently have the following regex

```
".*[0-9].*"
```

The above makes sure that the text has a number in it. I would also like to add the condition of minimum length to it say 8 characters. How can I add another condition to the above expression making sure that there are at least 8 characters in the text ?

Comment: I'm wondering can't you just use `strlen` ? Otherwise, if your regex engine supports lookahead assertions, you might use `^(?=.{8,}$).*[0-9].*$` [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/pJ7xQ0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You can use Positive Lookaheads to validate a string before capturing it.

---

### Regex

`(?=^.{8,}$)(?=^.*\d)^.*$`

---

### Explanation

The syntax for a Positive Lookahead is like so: `(?=REGEX)`

In the regex above, I have specified `^.{8,}$` inside the **first** Lookahead. This means that the string MUST have a MINIMUM of 8 characters from start to finish in order to pass validation.

The **second** positive lookahead has `^.*\d`. This means that the string can begin with any characters, but there must be a digit somewhere in the string, otherwise it will not pass validation.

The last bit is simply "match everything" `^.*$`, because if it passed the initial validation, then we want to capture it.

---

### Demonstration

[Regex101 Example](http://regex101.com/r/dX0mA0)

Answer (score 1):

The regex for checking minimum and maximum element goes as follow

```
{2}    contains 2 element 
{2,5}  contains 2 to 5 element 
{2,}   contains 2 or more
```

You can also check this  [PDF](http://www.night-ray.com/regex.pdf) file for more information

Good luck